# Is this a bad practice to implement optional parameters in SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider following query that runs on AdventureWorks2014 database:

```
DECLARE @OrderID int=43659, @ProdID int =-1;

SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = @OrderID
  AND sod.ProductID = CASE WHEN @ProdID = -1 THEN sod.ProductID ELSE @ProdID END
```

@ProdID is used as optional parameter. Sometimes I am interested in all items in the order and other times - only in items with specific ProductID. Part of WHERE clause that starts with AND serves this purpose.

If -1 is passed as value for @ProdID this part of WHERE is essentially ignored.

If I pass 771 as value for @ProdID I will only receive items with ProductID = 771.

This query is passed to SQL Server from codebehind from ASP.Net C# application. So in this particular case I can build the query dynamically and if ProdID parameter in C# is -1 I can completely omit part of the query that starts from AND and not pass value of ProdID to SQL at all. However, doing it the way as described above makes it easier to develop and debug (and in case I wanted to put this code in stored procedure later this is really the only way to go).

Is this a bad practice? Or is SQL Server "smart enough" to ignore "sod.ProductID=sod.ProductID" part in WHERE clause and it really has no effect on performance?

Comment: It's bad practice to do any calculations in your where clause if you can get away with it, your performance will take a nose dive.

Comment: most people do it like this:  where (( (at)ProdID IS NULL ) OR ( sod.ProductID = (at)ProdID ) ) ........the more "flexible" you make it, the slightly less it will perform (as a general rule of thumb)

Comment: it can lead to a poorer execution plan, which you should check for, check the query execution plan with and without the case statement - check there is no large scan introduced

Comment: I have always used an if statement and maintained two separate queries, one with a where statement and one without (also, please don't use *)

Comment: on my DB here, I did similar, and it changed a 'seek' for a given value into a table scan

Answer (score 3):

let program logic choose the appropriate query, otherwise you risk changing an efficient 'seek' that utilises an index into a scan

```
IF @ProdID = -1 THEN
    SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
    WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = @OrderID

ELSE
    SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
    WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = @OrderID
    AND sod.ProductID = @ProdID;
```

Comment: Do be careful with this approach. If this is a stored procedure you can still get very inefficient plans. You would need to either add OPTION RECOMPILE or create a "driver" procedure and split each of these queries into their own procedures.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @OrderID int=43659, @ProdID int =-1;

SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = @OrderID
  AND (@ProdID = -1 or sod.ProductID = @ProdID)
```

or pass a null @ProdID to get everything
this will probably be faster than the or

```
 AND isnull(@ProdID, sod.ProductID) = sod.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bad practice.

I apologize for answering my own question but I just received a couple great answers at MSDN that cover this topic in great detail, so credit really goes to them (or rather to the people who wrote articles they referred me to):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/12e2e169-987b-4df9-8696-44697aba15aa/is-this-a-bad-practice-to-implement-optional-parameters-in-sql-query?forum=transactsql

Articles linked from MSDN post:

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/high-performance-procedures/

http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ (this one also uses AW database as an example)